# How to search Google Maps centered around coordinates?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I'm trying to search places around a certain coordinate. I tried this but it doesn't work:

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=groceries&center=37.33233141,-122.0312186`

I could not find anything in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide). I needed this to work or universal, cross-platform devices so it would open the browser or Google Map app if available.

If it helps, I can do this with Apple Maps like this: `http://maps.apple.com/?q=mosque&sll=37.33233141,-122.0312186`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) , specifically [Nearby Search requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests):

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY`